# can't start spyder ide the ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library [mkl_intel_thread.dlll]

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

i've installed spyder IDE with anaconda but when i start the program i got error massage:

> the ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library

My Python version is 3.7.3.

Comment: This should be fixed by updating Python to its latest version with `conda update python`.

Answer (score 1):

In the anaconda prompt type:

```
set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
```